# Arrays.sort throwing class cast exception

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, casting

The Arrays.sort function throws ClassCastException in the following scenario:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object[] obj = {
                new String("string"),
                new Integer(10)
        };
        Arrays.sort(obj);
    }
```

I would expect an exception here, and the error message says:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer  at
>   java.lang.Integer.compareTo(Integer.java:52)  at
>   java.util.ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(ComparableTimSort.java:290)
>     at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:157)     at
>   java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:146)  at
>   java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:472)

Is the sort() function is trying to cast the first value in array to second value?
I reversed the elements in Object array to:

```
Object[] obj = {
                    new Integer(10),
                    new String("string")
            };
```

Now the Exception says that Integer cannot be cast to String:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String  at
>   java.lang.String.compareTo(String.java:108)   at
>   java.util.ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(ComparableTimSort.java:290)
>     at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:157)     at
>   java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:146)  at
>   java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:472)

I know sorting in this scenario is not possible, but what exactly is happening internally?

Comment: How do you expect to sort a string and an integer?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I think he knows that he can't. I think he's asking for what java is **trying** to do.

Comment: @Sortirios Yes I know I cant! But I am wondering about how it works! Updated the question...

Comment: Java is trying its best to make sense of a nonsense situation.

Comment: @HotLicks but how are they doing it? It seems very interesting the way they are handling it!

Comment: Just look at the code yourself.

Comment: I guess Java is just trying to compare the two elements. It can't compare only one element so basically : it goes to the second element, sees it's an Integer / a String, tries to cast the first element to that type to compare it with the second and baam, ClassCastException.

Comment: @Jerk31 makes sense! Thanks! But I still don't know why my question is downvoted! I hope stack overflow sends message (anonymous atleast) as to why they down voted!

Comment: The main thing I find confusing is that the exception is reported out of compareTo in both cases, yet neither class implements `compareTo(Object)`, so the cast would in theory have had to be attempted by the caller.  So I can't explain the precise exception trace.  (Though maybe Sontirios's answer explains this.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Arrays.sort` use the `Comparable` interface to sort element. You can think of it like this: each element will be cast in a `Comparable` object and the method `compareTo` will be called. The problem is that Integer implement the `compareTo` methods as `compareTo(Integer i)` while `String` use `compareTo(String s)`. So java will try to cast `String` into an `Integer` when calling the `compareTo` method of `Integer` resulting in a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Now that you said, it looks simple logic! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object[])

> Sorts the specified array of objects into ascending order, according
>   to the natural ordering of its elements. All elements in the array
>   must implement the Comparable interface. Furthermore, all elements in
>   the array must be mutually comparable (that is, e1.compareTo(e2) must
>   not throw a ClassCastException for any elements e1 and e2 in the
>   array).

In order to sort Strings and Integers, you must be able to cast in BOTH directions. It's simply failing out at the first ClassCastException, which happens to be different depending on how the array is declared.

The fact that you get a different exception each time, is just implementation defined.

Answer (score 2):

For `Arrays#sort(Object[])` to work, the elements within have to be `Comparable` to each other. Take for example this class

```
public class Example implements Comparable<Example>{
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Example o) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

When you compile this, the compiler adds a synthetic method (the second one below) where there is an explicit cast to whatever type argument is used in the `extends Comparable<HERE>` declaration

```
 public int compareTo(Example);
    descriptor: (LExample;)I
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=2, args_size=2
         0: iconst_0      
         1: ireturn       
      LineNumberTable:
        line 6: 0

  public int compareTo(java.lang.Object);
    descriptor: (Ljava/lang/Object;)I
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_BRIDGE, ACC_SYNTHETIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=2, args_size=2
         0: aload_0       
         1: aload_1       
         2: checkcast     #2                  // class Example
         5: invokevirtual #3                  // Method compareTo:(LExample;)I
         8: ireturn       
      LineNumberTable:
        line 1: 0
```

This is necessary in order to retain type safety. When `sort` starts comparing elements, it only has `Object` (`Comparable`) references. So it does

```
comparableRef.compareTo(otherComparableRef);
```

Internally, casts occur so that you can compare types safely and correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Literally from [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object[])):

> Throws:
>   `ClassCastException` - if the array contains elements that are not mutually comparable (for example, strings and integers)

When we look at the source at `java.util.ComparableTimSort.Java:232` we can see this happening:

```
if (pivot.compareTo(a[mid]) < 0)
```

which brings us to the documentation of the [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)) interface:

> Throws:
>   `ClassCastException` - if the specified object's type prevents it from being compared to this object.

Stacktrace to get here:

```
Arrays.sort() -> Arrays.java:468
ComparableTimSort.sort() -> Arrays.java:472
sort() -> ComparableTimSort.java:145
sort() -> ComparableTimSort.java:149
binarySort() -> ComparableTimSort.java:213
compareTo() -> ComparableTimSort.java:232
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling the `Arrays#sort` method will evalute the `Array` you have provided as an entry and through the *sort* algorithm, it will call the `Comparable#comapareTo` method on each `Object`. This comparison goes in both ways will result in the different exception traces when you switch the objects order.

[Here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.sort%28java.lang.Object[]%29) you can take a look at the `java.util.Arrays#sort` method.